# linkd keybindings conflicts w/ mouse scrolling

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm suffering of keybindings from [`linkd.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/linkd.el), which overrides `mouse-4` and binds it to `linkd-back`.
I've tried to remove or revert back but I couldn't.
Please let me know if you know how to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this in your init file. It will remove those key bindings provided by [`linkd.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/linkd.el):

```el
(eval-after-load "linkd"
  '(progn (define-key linkd-overlay-map [mouse-4] nil)
          (define-key linkd-map         [mouse-4] nil)))
```

Comment: In that case, please consider accepting the answer. Thx.